# Quantidade de registros que não atendem determinado filtro

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho essa query:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabela WHERE campo != "";
```

Qual a forma de saber a quantidade de registros que não atendem essa condição?

Eu sei que posso criar outra query e utilizar o **affected rows** consigo ter os 2 valores  e comparar  mas eu queria saber se existe uma maneira mais rápida.

Comment: Faz um count da tabela inteira, depois faça um count com essa condição e subtraia os dois resultados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não consigo  afirmar se o MySQL possui uma função nativa pra isso, mas como sugerido pelo @rray, você pode fazer um subselect com a quantidade total de registros e também com a quantidade de registros filtrados e subtrair ambos e obter o resultado que você espera.

```
SELECT (c.Total - cc.Retorno) AS Total
FROM (
  (SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total FROM contatos) c, 
  (SELECT COUNT(1) as Retorno FROM contatos WHERE endereco != '') cc
);
```

Algo mais simples seria inverter sua condição:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM contatos WHERE endereco = '';
```

Você pode ver a query em funcionamento no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b65f/5/0)